# Loading jsRender remote templates never updates

Tags: jquery, jsrender

I am trying to load jsRender templates from a text file with this bit of code

```
 $.get('/js/templates/template1.txt', function (value) {
        ..do stuff;
});
```

And this works fine until I change the template.  After I change the template the txt file is never reloaded and my rendered HTML never reflects the change unless I change the name of the txt file.

Is there any way to clear the object or whatever or can anybody explain why it doesnt want to reload the txt file.

EDIT:

Here is the code in the function to render the template with data passed in (the '..do stuff. area from above)

```
 var personTemplate = $.templates(value);
 var html = personTemplate.render(inputData);
 $(selectorName).html(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably being cached on the server. You need to ensure the file is served with the appropriate header for the caching policy. For example if you are using node.js on the server you could write

`res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');`

or

`res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0');`

or similar.

Comment: can you elaborate?  Not using node.js simple jQuery on the client side that uses the text file to render the data with the template

Comment: To access a text file, you must be opening the html file for the page using a web server. So it depends on your environment, and the way that web server is configured for different file types. (On my system it works without needing to set cache to false). Also, try adding a .fail() call back to your jQuery ajax call. When you have updated the txt file does it  call success, or fail? - and if fail, what is the error message...

Comment: I get a success but I think its the server that is caching the txt file - see my answer above about changing to html file

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the cache when making the ajax query. You can do this in jQuery as follows

```
$.ajax({
    url: templatesUrl,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some experimenting lead me to believe that there is some sort of cache in play but it does not seem to be anything to do with jQuery or jsRender.

I tried a few different extensions and it seems that the .html extension keeps it from being cached.

Just info for anyone who runs into this

Also as .html files its easier to work with these in an IDE rather than .txt files